# Putting contents from a text field in one view to an array in another

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) to make a table in my app. In my app, I have a text field in my AddTransactionViewController. Users enter data in this field many times. In another view, I want a table with all of the entries the user made. I was trying to figure out how to do this within the array. I need some help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an `NSMutableArray` and add the text field value to every time AddTransactionViewController is dismissed. Once you have the array ready, display it in the table view as you normally would.

I'd also recommend you check out the free Sensible TableView framework. Should save you tons of time with collecting data and automatically displaying your arrays in table views.

Comment: I haven't really looked into the mutable thing yet. I guess now is the time to do it. I will take a look at Sensible TableView. Thanks for the help. By the way, could you tell me how to actually use the NSMutableArray?

Comment: Assuming you have an AddTransactionViewController property called textField, whenever the view controller is dismissed, call [textMutableArray addObject:addTransactionViewController.textField.text];

Answer (score 0):

Now I see what you are asking. When the user presses a button save the text of the UITextField into 1 array. When you segue to the other view controller send the array to the other view controller. Insert the data to the tableview.

Passing Data:

```
   #import "SecondVC"      

  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
       SecondVC *secondVc = [[SecondVC alloc]init];
       secondVC.secondArray = self.myArray;
 }
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I get the idea of what you are saying. I should use the `prepareForSegue` method. But could you tell me how to do this in more detail?

Comment: Of course! Create an NSMutableArray and save the text of the UITextView in the array. Make an array in the tableviewcontroller in the h file. Once you got all the data in the array use the prepare for segue method. In the prepare for segue send the data from the array in which you got the data and put it in the array you made in the tableviewcontroller. Then in the tableviewcontroller follow the tableview delegate and insert the data from your array.

Comment: No. How do I send the data?

Comment: When saving the textfield contents to the array, it only stores one piece of data. When the user re-activates the textfield for use again, it replaces the previous content in the array.

Comment: How are you inserting the data in the array?